# SQL join on table different from source table

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
select distinct
  u.id, 
  v1.code,
  v2.code,
  a1.phone,
  a1.phone1,
  SUM(o1.totalprice) as SALES
  SUM(ot4.numbers) as NUMBERS
from 
  users u,
  orders o2
 inner join values v1 on v1.pk = u.gender
 inner join values v2 on v2.pk = u.egistration
 inner join addresses a1 on a1.owner = u.pk 
 inner join orders o1 on o1.userpk = u.pk
 inner join orderthings ot4 on ot4.orderpk = o2.pk 
where 
  u.cccustomer = 1
and
  v2.code = 'REGISTERED'
group by
  u.id, 
  v1.code,
  v2.code,
  a1.phone,
  a1.phone1
order by 
  id;
```

Basically the join on orders doesn't work but I need to get the additional relation on the two tables that have no relation to users u. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: To clarify: I think already the second table in from is wrong. I have no idea how to add a join from two tables that have nothing to do with users u.

Comment: you don't.  to get the cartesian product, or all users for each result row, list the table in the from clause without any ON references.

Comment: @BenSchnitzel can you post the table structures and sample data and the desired results?  Or even better create a sql fiddle with a working data model.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL language tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322297/sql-language-tutorial)

Comment: Here's a fiddle of what I'm trying to do: with a second join that does not contain the u but o get the an.string in the same query that hast the join on u: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7cce/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7cce/2), if your tables don't relate to one another, then you can use a `CROSS JOIN` to join them, similar to this:

```
select u.Email, 
  v1.String Gender, 
  v2.String Title, 
  o.a_string, 
  o.o_string
from users u
inner join value v1
   on u.Gender = v1.PK
inner join value v2
   on u.Title = v2.PK
cross join
(
  select a.PK, a.string a_string, o.string o_string
  from another a
  inner join other o
    on a.PK = o.PK
) o;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d93b8/3)